# How should I reference CSS in a django app?

Tags: django

I am trying to use a Django app - django-tables2.  The [tutorial](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) refers to a CSS stylesheet in the app.  However, I get a 404 on the stylesheet.  How does my app refer to the stylesheet in django-tables2?

I get a 404 for : http://127.0.0.1:8000/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css

Comment: Are your css file inside `django-tables2/static/django-tables2/css` folder?

Comment: I don't have any of my files. I just want to use the tutorial.  The tutorial refers to the stylesheet which is part of the django-tables2 app, which I installed.